# How to remove both the inline as well as written is css file in moovweb?

Tags: jquery, moovweb

I want to remove the inline and external css applied to the particular div.

I don't want to use remove_all_styles() which removes all the styles of the page.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Does removing both style and class attributes do the trick?

```
$("#ParticularDiv").removeAttr("class").removeAttr("style");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try;

```
$("#div"){
    remove_attributes()
}
```

Then you would have a blank slate.

Answer (score 0):

Remove inline css of a particular div

```
$('#div_id').removeAttr('style');
```

Or you can do it in your css also bu using `not` attribute.

In html:

```
<button class="nostyle">
```

In css:

```
button:not(.nostyle) {
```

[Usefull fiddle by Danny Beckett](http://jsfiddle.net/4PgQw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by selecting that `div` using tritium and then using the `attribute(...)` function to clear out the `style` attribute.  Say I had the following html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="background: red">Hi</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I could write the following tritium to remove the inline style:

```
$("/html/body/div") {
  attribute("style", "")
}
```

A shortcut to this is using the `remove(...)` function in tritium.  With some XPath magic, you can turn the above code into a one-liner like so:

```
remove("/html/body/div/@style")
```

And that should remove the inline styles associated with that `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it by $('#div') {remove_atributes()} which will remove all the attributes inside div else you can go for remove_class('ClassName') which will remove class containing style